Extract bounded region from implicit region
The region $x^3\le y\le x^2$ consists of two regions. Reduce shows it.
Reduce[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {x, y}] outputs (x < 0 && x^3 <= y <= x^2) || (x == 0 && y == 0) || (0 < x < 1 && x^3 <= y <= x^2) || (x == 1 && y == 1)
The first region is unbounded (x<0) and second region is bounded (0<=x<=1).
How to extract only bounded regions? In this case I want only the region on the interval (0<=x<=1).
The second question is why two points are separated? Namely (x == 0 && y == 0) and (x == 1 && y == 1).
EDIT.
All answers try to get regions from reduce and find their measure.
In general this doesn't work, because the unbounded region can be adjacent to the "bounded" and so they are counted as unbounded.
Consider the following example:
Reduce[y >= (x - 1)^3 && y <= -x + 3 && y <= x + 3, {x, y}]
Its region is

Clearly the region is unbounded, but Reduce has splitted it into an unbounded and bounded.
In this case there are no bounded regions.

I do not understand the question.  If you want only the region 0<=x<=1 why don't you use x^3 <= y <= x^2 && 0 <= x <= 1?

@azerbajdzan , because I don't know ahead where bounded region is located. In general I want to extract bounded subregions from the region, described by some constraints.

Then maybe this is too simple of an example, but anyway I posted an answer that works for this specific case.

@azerbajdzan, see edit.

So you want for your new example to return {}?

@azerbajdzan, exactly.

I do not think that Mathematica has build-in function that can do that automatically for any regions (imagining how complicated regions can be). It can be done for a specific region but you have to assist Mathematica.

You say "The region $^3≤≤^2$ consists of two regions." I claim that this is mathematically incorrect statement. Probably, you talk about the connected components. But even this is not correct, the region is connected as per definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space

Possibly, I've use incorrect words, but I've provided examples to be more clear.

If two regions have a common point---it is actually one connected region. Common point is $x=0, y=0$

Select[Reduce[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {x, y}], 
  Area@ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] < Infinity &] /. 
 Thread[{Less, Greater} -> {LessEqual, GreaterEqual}]


0 <= x <= 1 && x^3 <= y <= x^2


Use...
sol = Reduce[x^3 < y < x^2, {x, y}];
ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ sol;
RegionMeasure[#] & /@ %

Or...
sol = Reduce[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {x, y}];
Select[sol, RegionMeasure@ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] < Infinity &]


Please see edit with a counterexample.

Yep.  You're right.  Needs more work... [Give me a bit and I'll repost an answer later today]. I think we'll need to use SymmetricRegionDifference and RegionUnion to compute the contiguous (joined) regions, and then compute the areas...
